# Suggestions To Wiki Texts Not Possible

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I wanted to modify the wiki text of the [design](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) tag here on Meta, in order to give more information about the usage of the tag:

- [Excerpt](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/23)
- [Wiki Text](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/22)

ChrisF rejected the suggestions with the following statement:

> Tag wiki's on Meta are pushed from Me ta Stack Overflow - your edits will be overwritten. Better to suggest changes on MSO

I checked both the original wiki texts and they are not identical:

- Original text [design](/questions/tagged/design) tag on Meta Web Applications: [Wiki
  Text](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/design/info)
- Original text [design](/questions/tagged/design) tag on Meta Stack Overflow: [enter link
  description here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/design/info)

If they are being pushed, were from? And Why can't prepare our own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK - my information is definitely out of date in that case.

The theory was that tag wikis would be pushed out, but as pointed out in [this answer on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92219/proposing-tag-wiki-creation-does-not-work-on-meta-sites/121066#121066)

> sometimes the tag wikis we float to the child metas do not properly fit the community.

I can only blame old age for forgetting about this.

Please suggest the edits again and I'll accept them.

Comment: The old theory was that tag wikis would be updated periodically from MSO to child metas. As far as I know, this never happened, and tag wikis were only ever populated when the sites were created. At that time, it was not possible to edit tag wikis on child metas (not even if you were a mod). [Then it became possible to edit tag wikis on child metas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92219/proposing-tag-wiki-creation-does-not-work-on-meta-sites/121066#121066), and there is no reason to reject such edits on principle.

Comment: Al reviewed the wiki suggestions, but the status is still telling me it needs to be peer reviewed. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra - it normally takes two reviewers. The exception is if the first reviewer is a mod, then it gets accepted or rejected straight away.